# Filter Elements: Display parent elements based on children classes

Tags: javascript

The code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FP4G4XPN4ICA

```js
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function filterSelection2(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv2");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('colors')"> Colors</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection2('fruits')"> Fruits</button>
</div>

<ul class="container">
  <li class="filterDiv"><div class="filterdiv2 fruits">apple</div></li>
  <li class="filterDiv cars">Volvo</li>
  <li class="filterDiv colors">Red</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to achieve: 
When the button "Fruits" is clicked, the li elements containing children elements containing the class "fruits" to be displayed.

What should I change/rewrite in the method filterSelection2() to do that?

Comment: Your code would be more readable if you were using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList that helps adding/removing/toggling/checking classes on an element, and you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector to check if there is an element matching a CSS selector or not in the subtree

Comment: The code is not mine. I am trying to learn based on an example from w3school. The original example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two different `filterSelection()` methods:

Better try this way:

```js
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == 'all') {
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
      if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('colors')"> Colors</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')"> Fruits</button>
</div>

<ul class="container">
  <li class="filterDiv fruits">apple</li>
  <li class="filterDiv cars">Volvo</li>
  <li class="filterDiv colors">Red</li>
</ul>
```